# How to pass value from datagridview to textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, contextmenu

I am currently working on a system. I have a datagridview with a contextmenu and an edit and delete button on it. I want to pass the value of the selected rows to a textbox when I click the edit on contextmenu.

I have successfully passed the value to the textbox but the only values that show are from the last inputted data to whatever row I click. I don't know how to get the id, can someone please help me fix my problem? :(

Here is my code:

```cs
private void BtnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmAddEditStudent frm = new frmAddEditStudent(this);

    cn.Open();
    cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT s.studentID, s.studentNo, s.Lname, s.Fname, s.MI, s.gender, s.yearLevel, s.section, s.studImage, g.name, g.contactNo, g.address FROM Student s INNER JOIN Guardian g ON g.studentNo = s.studentNo WHERE g.studentNo = s.studentNo AND s.isActive = 'true' AND s.studentID = studentID", cn);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("studentID", lblID.Text);

    for (int i = 0; i < guna2DataGridView1.Rows.Count; i += 1)
    {
        frm.btnSave.Enabled = false;
        frm.lblTitle.Text = "Edit Student Details";
        frm.lblID.Text = guna2DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        frm.txtStudentNo.Text = guna2DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        frm.txtLname.Text = guna2DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        frm.txtFname.Text = guna2DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        frm.txtMI.Text = guna2DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        frm.cboGradeLevel.Text = guna2DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        frm.cboSection.Text = guna2DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        frm.txtGuardianName.Text = guna2DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
        frm.txtContactNo.Text = guna2DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
        frm.txtAddress.Text = guna2DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value.ToString();

        //Load Image
        byte[] bytes = (byte[])guna2DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        frm.studImage.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

        //Retrieve gender value to radio button
        if (guna2DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString() == "Male")
        {
            frm.rbMale.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            frm.rbFemale.Checked = true;
        }

    }
    cn.Close();
    frm.ShowDialog();
```

It does not show up the data in the row that I selected, instead it only shows the last row in my database table.

Comment: Don't pass any values. Create binding

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current row or the selected rows from a datagridview in the following way (I think ID is cell with Index 1):

```
Console.WriteLine(guna2DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString());

foreach (DataGridViewRow loRow in guna2DataGridView1.CurrentRow.SelectedRows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(loRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
}
```

But you overwrite the form values in your loop every time.
It seems that your form can only display one row and not a collection.
And what about the command cm??